# jackson serialize different time zones into single time zone

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, timezone

I have multiple timezones and I want to have them exactly after serialization, but `jackson` convert them into single time zone if I set `DateFormat` all zones convert to context time zone and if I don't set `DateFormat` all zones convert to `UTC` (zero time zone).

I know that we have `DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE` in deserialization and we can disable it but I can't find something like this in `SerializationFeature`.

Is there anyway that I can tell `jackson` to don't convert timezones?

here is my test class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;


public class Test {

    public static class flight {
        private XMLGregorianCalendar dateDeparture;
        private XMLGregorianCalendar dateArrival;

        public XMLGregorianCalendar getDateDeparture() {
            return dateDeparture;
        }

        public void setDateDeparture(XMLGregorianCalendar dateDeparture) {
            this.dateDeparture = dateDeparture;
        }

        public XMLGregorianCalendar getDateArrival() {
            return dateArrival;
        }

        public void setDateArrival(XMLGregorianCalendar dateArrival) {
            this.dateArrival = dateArrival;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DatatypeConfigurationException, JsonProcessingException {
        XMLGregorianCalendar dateDeparture = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(2018,1,22,10,15,0,0, TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Istanbul").getRawOffset()/1000/60);
        XMLGregorianCalendar dateArrival = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(2018,1,22,13,30,0,0,TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Dubai").getRawOffset()/1000/60);
        System.out.println("Local Departure Time=" + dateDeparture);
        System.out.println("Local Arrival Time=" + dateArrival);

        flight flight = new flight();
        flight.setDateDeparture(dateDeparture);
        flight.setDateArrival(dateArrival);

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        xmlMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ"));
        String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(flight);
        System.out.println(xml);
    }
}
```

here is the output:

```
Local Departure Time=2018-01-22T10:15:00.000+03:00
Local Arrival Time=2018-01-22T13:30:00.000+04:00
<flight><dateDeparture>2018-01-22T10:45:00+0330</dateDeparture><dateArrival>2018-01-22T01:00:00+0330</dateArrival></flight>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could think of is to create your own serialize module so to be able to handle `XMLGregorianCalendar` serialization all by yourself. Unfortunately Java has proven not to be good in handling dates.

```
public class XMLCalendarSerializer extends StdSerializer<XMLGregorianCalendar> {
    public XMLCalendarSerializer() {
        this((Class)null);
    }

    public XMLCalendarSerializer(Class<XMLGregorianCalendar> t) {
        super(t);
    }

   public void serialize(XMLGregorianCalendar value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        DateFormat dateFormatt = provider.getConfig().getDateFormat();
        if(dateFormatt.getCalendar() == null) {
            jgen.writeString(value.toString());
        } else {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = (SimpleDateFormat)dateFormatt;
            GregorianCalendar a = value.toGregorianCalendar();
            Date date = value.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
            dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(value.getTimeZone(value.getTimezone()).getDisplayName()));
            jgen.writeString(dateFormat.format(date));
        }

    }
}
```

and the module class would be like:

```
public class XMLCalendarModule extends SimpleModule {
    private static final String NAME = "CustomXMLCalendarModule";
    private static final VersionUtil VERSION_UTIL = new VersionUtil() {
};

    public XMLCalendarModule() {
        super("CustomXMLCalendarModule", VERSION_UTIL.version());
        this.addSerializer(XMLGregorianCalendar.class, new XMLCalendarSerializer());
    }
}
```

and you can simply register this module like:

```
xmlMapper.registerModule(new XMLCalendarModule());
```